# Find parent of the submenu items in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to find out parent when i click on the submenu item. For example in the image below when i click on L3B the result should be "L1/L2/L3B".

[image: Popup menu]

Comment: Please, do as you wish.

Comment: You are supposed to ask a question at this site. However, there's no need to for your problem. You can simply read the documentation.

Comment: I think that you mean 'L1/L2/L3A'. However, that is not the parent of L3B. The parent of L3B is the menu item with text L3A. I think you want to recursively find the texts of parents of the menu item, as long as that parent is itself a menu item, and then concatenate the texts with some separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to get the full path of your menu.

```
function Form1.GetMenuPath(Menu: TMenuItem): String;
begin
  if (Menu.Parent <> nil) and (Menu.Parent.ClassType = TMenuItem) then
    Result := GetMenuPath(TMenuItem(Menu.Parent));
  if Result <> '' then
    Result := Result + ' > ';
  Result := Result + Menu.Caption;
end;
```

At your MenuItemClick you call the function

```
procedure Form1.L3B1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(GetMenuPath(TMenuItem(Sender)));
end;
```